# Android: Making content scrollable with keyboard without resizing background

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RelativeLayout` and inside it I have a `LottieAnimationView` and another `LinearLayout`. The LottieAnimationView serves as my background image and inside the LinearLayout I have my content with `EditText` and `Button`. So my problem is now that the content shall be scrollable when the softkeyboard is out but the background image shall not be resized. I have tried several things but nothing really worked.

My XML looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LottieAnimationView>
    <ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>
            <EditText>
            <Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Would making the `LottieAnimationView` a child of the `ScrollView` possibly be a solution?

Comment: try  <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen making the `LottieAnimationView` a child of the `LinearLayout` / `ScrollView` scales the animation view wrong. It does not fit the screen size although im setting it to `match_parent`

Comment: This looks really nasty, and maybe the Lottie view is not that flexible.  If you really get stuck here then maybe consider an alternative.

Comment: @rajahsekar `<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>` does not work the way I want it to. I want the content to resize but the background shall not resize.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok, i found a solution. I did put the `LottieAnimationView` inside the `LinearLayout` and i had to set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to the Lottie view so it scales the right way.

Comment: @Cimoe You can post that as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Solution:

I had to put the `LottieAnimationView` inside the `LinearLayout` and set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to the Lottie View.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set match_parent to your ImageView or LottieAnimationView in the layout xml and then in the activity/fragment/view set it's height to the current:

```
val height = yourBackgroundImageView.height 
if (height > 0) {
   yourBackgroundImageView.setHeight(height)
}
```

Just make sure it's done after the view was attached to the screen (and measured).